# How can I eject a CD from MacOS with Python?

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to use something like `ioctl(fd, CDROMEJECT, 0)`, but I don't know how to get the `fd` referring to the CDROM in the first place.

I've looked into `/dev` and `/Volumes` and found nothing related.

Is there any other way to execute the `ejection`?

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/114515/how-can-i-find-what-dev-my-dvd-drive-is

Comment: Also helpful example at http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/614751-help-controlling-cdrom-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Have you tried using a system call?**

### Mac OS X

Eg. Try this in your Terminal

```
python -c 'import os; os.system("drutil tray open")'
```

I just tried this on my MacBook Pro, let me know if this helps!

Code:

```
import os

os.system("drutil tray open")
```

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/26/quick-tip-eject-media-from-the-command-line/

### Linux

```
import os

os.system("eject -t cdrom")
```

Source: http://opentechlab.blogspot.com/2009/06/play-with-cdrom-in-linux.html

### Windows

**Using "cytpes" module:**

```
import ctypes, time

# open the CD tray 
ctypes.windll.winmm.mciSendStringW("set cdaudio door open", None, 0, None)

# try closing the tray
ctypes.windll.winmm.mciSendStringW("set cdaudio door closed", None, 0, None)
```

Source: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/72834/handling-cd-drives-from-python

### Universal

**Using "pygame" module: [Download here](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)**

```
import pygame.cdrom as cdrom

cdrom.init()
cd = cdrom.CD(0)
cd.init()
cd.eject()
cd.quit()
cdrom.quit()
```

Source: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/614751-help-controlling-cdrom-python

**Using "pymedia" module: [Download here](http://pymedia.org/):**

Documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cdrom.html

http://pymedia.org/docs/pymedia.removable.cd.html

There seems to be an 'eject' function within the library:

> eject() eject or open the cdrom drive eject() -> None This will open
>   the cdrom drive and eject the cdrom. If the drive is playing or paused
>   it will be stopped.

Source: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/cdrom.html#pygame.cdrom.CD.eject

Regards,

Comment: BTW, is there anyway I can use `ioctl`? or is it Linux specific?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is for Unix/Linux. http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html. It may or may not work exactly as intended for Mac OSX.

Comment: I know what you mean, I simply have not tried it and I am trying to give you as much help as possible :)

Comment: I'm still trying to accomplish it with `ioctl`.